How to filter array Json data in Azure search index?
I need to search JSON data in Azure Search Index, but the query is not working to filter Json array data.
{
    "select": "id, data/prices",
    "filter": "data/prices ne null"
}

Error received:

Invalid expression: The operand for a binary operator 'NotEqual' is not a single value. Binary operators require both operands to be single values.\r\nParameter name: $filter

Is there any way to filter array type of data as well?
Below is my items data which is available in Index.
"data": {
  "prices": [
       {
         "currency": "IN",
         "price": 99,
       }
   ]
}

Thanks in advance!

try this filter data/prices/any(price: price ne 'null') and refer to the sample Odata filter expression mentioned here.

Thanks, VenkateshDodda. filter is not working and given us this type of error -
"Invalid expression: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'search.complex.raw.prices' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'NotEqual'.\r\nParameter name: $filter"

@Lazx if Json data from blob "filter": "content/value/any(v: v/data/prices/any(price: price/currency ne null))"

@Lazx data/prices/any(p: p/currency ne null )

The filter below  retrieves documents where at least one element in the "prices" array has a non-null currency and a non-zero price.
{

"select": "id, data/prices",

"filter": "data/prices/any(p: p/currency ne null and p/price ne 0)"

}


Fields of  Indexes:

Indexers:

Output:
The above filter expression checks each element in the "prices" array within the "data" object for each document. It filters documents where at least one element in the "prices" array has a non-null currency (p/currency ne null) and a non-zero price (p/price ne 0).

This sample data I used:
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "data": {
      "prices": [
        {
          "currency": "IN",
          "price": 99
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "data": {
      "prices": [
        {
          "currency": "IN",
          "price": 75
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "data": {
      "prices": [
        {
          "currency": "GBP",
          "price": 30
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "data": {
      "prices": [
        {
          "currency": null,
          "price": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

